# ImportError: cannot import name 'extract_zipped_paths'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to access the listed datasets in Tensorflow 2.0.  I use Windows 10.

I have run the following commands:

```
pip install tfds-nightly

pip install tensorflow-datasets
```

The version of Tensorflow in my PC is:

```
2.0.0-alpha0
```

(An attempt to upgrade it to the more recent version b run into an exception:

```
  Found existing installation: wrapt 1.10.11
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'wrapt'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

)

When I try to import the module:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
```

I get the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-46a8a2031c9c> in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\__init__.py in <module>()
     44 # needs to happen before anything else, since the imports below will try to
     45 # import tensorflow, too.
---> 46 from tensorflow_datasets.core import tf_compat
     47 tf_compat.ensure_tf_install()
     48 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\__init__.py in <module>()
     21 tf_compat.ensure_tf_install()
     22 
---> 23 from tensorflow_datasets.core.dataset_builder import BeamBasedBuilder  # pylint:disable=g-import-not-at-top
     24 from tensorflow_datasets.core.dataset_builder import BuilderConfig
     25 from tensorflow_datasets.core.dataset_builder import DatasetBuilder

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\dataset_builder.py in <module>()
     33 from tensorflow_datasets.core import constants
     34 from tensorflow_datasets.core import dataset_utils
---> 35 from tensorflow_datasets.core import download
     36 from tensorflow_datasets.core import file_format_adapter
     37 from tensorflow_datasets.core import lazy_imports_lib

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\download\__init__.py in <module>()
     17 
     18 from tensorflow_datasets.core.download.checksums import add_checksums_dir
---> 19 from tensorflow_datasets.core.download.download_manager import DownloadConfig
     20 from tensorflow_datasets.core.download.download_manager import DownloadManager
     21 from tensorflow_datasets.core.download.extractor import iter_archive

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\download\download_manager.py in <module>()
     32 from tensorflow_datasets.core import utils
     33 from tensorflow_datasets.core.download import checksums
---> 34 from tensorflow_datasets.core.download import downloader
     35 from tensorflow_datasets.core.download import extractor
     36 from tensorflow_datasets.core.download import resource as resource_lib

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\download\downloader.py in <module>()
     31 import promise
     32 import requests
---> 33 from requests.utils import extract_zipped_paths
     34 from six.moves import urllib
     35 import tensorflow as tf

ImportError: cannot import name 'extract_zipped_paths'
```

Comment: Have you tried updating the `requests` package?

Comment: Yes.  The requests package is updated.  However the error message persists.

Answer (score 3):

You need to downgrade the version of requests library to 2.21.0

```
pip install requests==2.21.0
```

I had the exact same problem, with **'2.0.0-beta1'** version of tensorflow, and had I pip installed tensorflow_datasets, which resulted in the error you have mentioned.

I noticed that while installing tensorflow_datasets, the requests module gets updated to latest version 2.22.0, which seems to be unable to import 'extract_zipped_paths', even though this function is defined in the requests.utils submodule, which you can find here:

https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/utils/

Also, the requests module seemed to be working just fine on its own, without TF. I dont know where the problem is originating from, but, downgrading the requests module to 2.21.0 works without any issue.

Summary:

```
tf.__version__ == '2.0.0-beta1'

pip install tensorflow_datasets 

pip install requests==2.21.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove all existing version of requests. And install specifically `pip install requests==2.22.0`